# My First React JS Portfolio Web App : A Restaurant Website

Tags: react.js, firebase

I have written my first react js web app. It is a portfolio project which is a restaurant website. I have used firebase to authenticate users and to host my website. I am asking the Code Review community to kindly review my code if there are scopes for improving and refactoring the code.

And I faced three problems while writing the app. The first problem is I am getting unused variables when using a context. Is there a better way to consume a context than below :

`const [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useContext(UserContext)`

And I am proving the values as below :

```html
<UserContext.Provider value={[loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser]}>
    <div>All content goes here</div>
 </UserContext.Provider>
```

And the second problem I faced is, I think, a lag between two computations. I have some protected routes, and I have set some `Link` elements that will redirect to the Login page if a user hasn't logged in. The problem is that when a user clicks on a link, he gets redirected to the login page even if he has logged in. I have set another redirection to redirect logged-in users to the profile page from the login page. So just in a second, the wrongly logged-in user is being redirected to the profile page. I think it can be solved using async/await. But how can I do this?

The third React Router Link element inside a Router element isn't working. The URL is changing on the address bar but the content isn't changing.

Here is my [repository link](https://github.com/RafidMuhymin/red-onion-react-and-firebase-project/) and the [live website](https://red-onion-restaurant-63e12.web.app/) link.